# Run file via subprocess from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, subprocess

When I run `cleaner.py` I want it to run `duplicate.py` and store the output in a variable.
So how do I locate to a directory in the Terminal via **subprocess**? I've already tried using:

```
output = subprocess.run('python duplicate.py', cwd = '/files', capture_output = True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the relative path answer by mnagel-- I also found specifying the args as a list is required in this case.  Otherwise subprocess throws a FileNotFoundError looking for `python ./duplicate.py`.

```
output = subprocess.run(['python', './duplicate.py'], cwd = './files', capture_output = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`/files` is an absolute path pointing to `/files` in the root directory `/`.
most likely you want to use `./files`

Comment: This did solve the problem when I also implemented **odenS0n**'s answer in my code. Thank you! :)